# QGIS lines multipart to singlepart without splitting at self-intersection

Tags: qgis, splitting, multipart, singlepart

I have a line layer and a vector grid. Now I want to count the lines in each raster. First I split the lines by intersecting the line layer with the vector grid.

Second, I need to do a multipart to singlepart for the lines because I want to count each line individually.

Now here is the problem: The lines are intersecting itself and at every intersection, the multipart-to-singlepart tool makes new parts of the lines.

How can I avoid this, are there other workarounds?

[image: A picture als explanation:]

Comment: "a vector raster"  what is it ?

Comment: Sorry, wrong translation, I meant Vector grid


(Vector -> research Tools -> Vector grid)

Comment: How many features do you need to do this for?

Comment: The vector grid is built by 378 polygons. I have more than 100 lines (not all of them with self-intersection), after intersecting them with the vector grid there are more than 2000. And after executing multipart-to-singlepart more than 3000....